# Stuck on jQuery blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting stuck on this and it's really frustrating.  I am trying to bind a function to the blur event on a series of page elements so that when they each loose focus, the function is fired off.  I am able to see the element's id print to the console as expected but adding to the blur event does not seem to work.

I am using jQuery (2.0.3) and I thought the following code would work:

```
$('div.myDiv').each(function(index, element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    element.blur(function() {
        console.log("Handler for .blur called.");
    });
});
```

The HTML of the elements looks something like this:

```
<div id="foo" class="myDiv" contenteditable="true">text 1</div>
<div id="baz" class="myDiv" contenteditable="true">text 2</div>
```

Comment: You should not have such generic "Stuck on jquery blur event" title. This is your condition not a question. It is misleading to people searching for actual questions related to code. 

Ask a functional question related to the code. This title implies that the onblur event is stuck in an infinite loop and causes the browser to hang or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element` is a DOM element and not a jquery object. So you could just bind it directly as:

```
$('div.myDiv').blur(function () {
    console.log("Handler for .blur called.");
});
```

With what you have you would do:

```
$('div.myDiv').each( function(index, element) {
    element.onblur = function() { //or use eventlistener to set the function reference.
        console.log("Handler for .blur called.");
    } ;
});
```

Comment: So in the first example, it would automatically perform a "each" loop to assign the function?  I am trying to understand how what you are mention works "under the hood."

Comment: @renderbox yes. You dont have to loop through yourself. Also remember that you can retrieve the id with just `this.id` shorter right

Comment: thanks for the background.  My confusion comes from other languages where your first answer looks like it would be a method on the the array object it's self and not a method on each of the items _in_ the array.  Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @renderbox Ideally of you do document.getElementsByClassName or document.querySelectorAll you need to loop through and attach the event. But `blur` is a jquery wrapper which will loop though and attach the blur event to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('div.myDiv').each( function() {
    console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
    $(this).blur( function() {
                      console.log("Handler for .blur called.");
                    }
                );
  });
```

Comment: `this` is not a jQuery object and will not produce the intended result.  Wrap it in `$(this)` and you're golden.  Either that or use `this.onblur = function() {}` instead

Comment: Interesting but in this case I am not sure how the scoping works for 'this' to function properly.  Again, asking to help the "under the hood" understanding.  :)